# Angular with filter in different view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a question concerning Angular and Angular-UI Router. I would like to place a filter in a bootstrap navbar which can vary depending on the current route. I have tried to implement this behaviour with Angular-UI Router but ui-router doesn't support sharing the same controller across multiple views. In their documentation the touch on this topic. See: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views.

I have created a plunker with the desired behaviour: http://plnkr.co/edit/W0UgeW

Onto my question: Is there any way I can accomplish this behaviour? I dont necissarly want to do it with Angular-ui Router, if it's at all possible without using extensions I would prefer to do it that way.

Thank you,

Bart

Comment: I think you will have to use angulars pub/sub methods.  Perhaps building a service to communicate between the navbar controller and the route's controller would be the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom filter like:

```
 myapp.filter('myfilter', function() {
   return function( items, combo) {
    var filtered = [];
     console.log(items, combo);
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
       if(item.name == combo){
         filtered.push(item);
       }

    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Now to pass combo option to view we can write:

```
 $rootScope.theFilter = '';
```

Our table will look like:

```
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | myfilter:theFilter">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TwghGij6VAqw4SpNPNcS?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer, but would prefer to not use the $rootScope for this. For now I will implement it like you suggested until I find a better way.

Comment: you can store it in service instead as well